# Append mode on Google Drive

Tags: google-drive-api

Is it possible to perform "append" operations on a file on Google Drive?

Let's say I want to save log entries "as-they-come-in" using Google Drive, is there some sort of "append only" operation available?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not currently possible to append data to a file in Drive without uploading a completely new copy of the file with the data appended.  This is a feature we're considering, but I don't have a timeline at this time.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to post this.